# bash: does expect work with multiple password prompts?

Tags: bash, ssh, passwords, expect

I am currently using expect to pass in passwords so my scripts can run automatically without me having to sit around and type in the same password over and over again.

Important: Please don't comment about how big of a security risk this is or how I should be using ssh keys, I would use those if I could, but the setup I have to work with doesn't allow it.

My code looks like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

PASS=mypassword

/usr/bin/expect -c "
spawn python Tools/python/install.py
expect -nocase \"password:\" {send \"$PASS\r\"; interact}
"
```

The problem I have is that install.py prompts for the same password a dozen times, it appears expect only auto fills the password for the first prompt.

Is there a way to modify the behavior so that it fills in the password all 12 times and not just the first time?

Comment: Any script that prompts your for the same password 12 times is broken. Fix install.py.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to do a little programming. Fortunately the answer is pretty simple:

```
#!/bin/sh

PASS=MyPassword
export PASS

/usr/bin/expect -c '
    spawn python Tools/python/install.py
    expect {
        -nocase "password:" {
            send "$env(PASS)\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        "somthing_else_that_indicates_you're_ready_to_interact"
    }
    interact
'
```

Cleaned up the shell quoting a little too.

Comment: Is there a way to make this return me back into the bash shell so my script can continue to execute other commands past this code block?

Comment: @user788171, just remove the `interact` line.