# continue script after expect{exp_continue}

Tags: bash, scripting, expect

I have bash code that looks like the following:

```
/usr/bin/expect -c '
    spawn python Tools/python/install.py
    expect {
        -nocase "password:" {
            send "$env(PASS)\r"
            exp_continue
        }
    }
    interact
'
```

This code seems to work except for the fact that after it submits the passwords, it hangs. After this block of code, there is more code I want to execute in my script. Is there a way to get expect to drop me back into the bash script to continue execution of lines below this block of code?

Comment: I'm guessing the `interact` command is biting you. From the man page, interact *gives control of the current process to the user, so that keystrokes are sent to the current process, and the stdout and stderr of the current process are returned*. Have you tried issuing this command in the background using `&` or `screen`?

Comment: yep, that's it, removal of interact does the trick!

Comment: This is a follow-up question to http://stackoverflow.com/q/11606149/7552

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Just to formally answer this question)...*

I'm guessing the `interact` command is biting you. From the man page:

> **interact** gives control of the current process to the user, so that keystrokes are sent to the current process, and the stdout and stderr of the current process are returned.

I would try either of these:

- Remove the `interact` command
- Issue the command in the background using `&` or `screen`

Based on your comment, it looks like the former was what worked.